# Next Div Does not appear correctly after floating two divs to right and left

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I have floated two divs to left and right...But the next div after those two divs does not appear correctly...
My code is follows

```
#Div1{ position: relative; float: left; }
#Div2{ position: relative; float: right; }
```

And the display as follows

```
<div id="Div1">This is aligned to left on the same x axis</div>
<div id="Div2">This is aligned to right on the same x axis</div>
<div style="color: red;">After the alignment this div does not align</div>
```

The output is as follows

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A6hz.png

But I expect something like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVGN6.png

Comment: add a `clear:both` to the style of the third div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. Insert clear both in the style.

```
 #Div1{ position: relative; float: left; }
 #Div2{ position: relative; float: right; }

<div id="Div1">This is aligned to left on the same x axis</div>
<div id="Div2">This is aligned to right on the same x axis</div>
<div style="color: red;clear:both;">After the alignment this div does not align</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand that whenever you use floats, you need to use

```
clear:both
```

for the subsequent divs which you don't wanted floated. What this does is clear any preceding floats.

So, as far as your code is concerned, you need to add:

```
clear: both
```

to the last div. That is,

```
<div style="color: red;">After the alignment this div does not align</div>
```

needs to be

```
    <div id="ClearedDiv">
       After the alignment this div does not align
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#ClearedDiv{
    color:red;
    clear:both;
}
```

You can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/WCT3m/

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

every float of multiple elements needs to clear after finishing, put

```
<br clear="all" />
```

or

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

it will be very good if you assign width to both elements.

This will be pretty for you

```
<style type="text/css">
   #Div1{ position: relative; float: left; width:49%; }
   #Div2{ position: relative; float: right; width:49%; }
</style>
<div id="Div1">This is aligned to left on the same x axis</div>
<div id="Div2">This is aligned to right on the same x axis</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div style="color: red;">After the alignment this div does not align</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

#Div1{position: relative; float: left;
#Div2{  position: relative; float: right;}
#Div3 { clear: both;}

<div id="Div1">This is aligned to left on the same x axis</div>
<div id="Div2">This is aligned to right on the same x axis</div>
<div id="Div3" style="color: red;">After the alignment this div does not align</div>
```